# Remove character '\xa0' while reading CSV file in python

Tags: python, csv, replace, encoding, character

I want to remove the non-ASCII Character '\xa0' while reading my CSV file using read_csv into a dataframe with python. Can someone tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `x = txt.replace(u'\xa0', u'')` for text you're reading.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Poo Not at all ;)